# Problema com acentuação ao gerar epub com gitbook

Tags: json

Estou com dificuldade para gerar um **epub** utilizando o **gitbook**. Realizei a instalação do gitbook-cli e do nodejs, posteriormente configurei o arquivo book.json da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "title": "Distribuição Debian",
    "description": "...",
    "author": "Fábio",
    "language": "pt"
}
```

Só que ao gerar o **epub** os metadados como **title**, **description** e **author** ficam "truncados" com caracteres irreconhecíveis no lugar dos acentos...

Print dos caracteres citados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria muito interessante ter o print dos caracteres ilegíveis ou então o resultado gerado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado atualizado com print

Comment: Eu acabei de obter um erro semelhante ao abrir um arquivo fonte que estava em ISO-8859-1 como se fosse UTF-8. Também não achei nada referente a encoding na documentação https://toolchain.gitbook.com/config.html